# Как определить позицию пользователя в соответствии запроса SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Приветствую. Появилась такая задача: вывести первых 3-х пользователей, чей рейтинг самый высокий и позицию самого пользователя в этом отсортированном списке, т.е 
есть пользователь `Вася` и его `рейтинг = 3000`, также есть пользователи `Коля`, `Дима`, `Петя`, чьи рейтинги соответственно равны `10 000`, `8 200` и `6000`.

Первый 3-х пользователей с высоким рейтингом можно получить так:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3
```

Получается так:

```
1. Коля
2. Дима
3. Петя
...
n. Вася
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли как-то с помощью одного запроса вывести первых 3-х пользователей и позицию `n` самого пользователя, относительно их рейтинга? 

Были решения с помощью цикла и счетчика, но мне, кажется, что это не самый лучший вариант или создавать отдельную таблицу. Как думаете Вы?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, ответ будет зависить от используемого диалекта SQL
Например в SQL Server (начиная с версии 2008) можно сделать что-нибудь в таком духе:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC) AS rn, name
    FROM users
    )
SELECT TOP 3 rn, name FROM cte
UNION 
SELECT rn, name FROM cte WHERE name = 'Вася'
ORDER BY rn
```

Comment: А, когда писал, не видел комментария, что речь о MySQL (хотя и следовало бы догадаться по LIMIT).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t3.name, t3.place
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t2.rating) place
    FROM table t1, table t2
    WHERE t1.rating <= t2.rating
    GROUP BY t1.name
) t3
WHERE t3.place < 4 
   OR t3.name = 'Вася'
```